# When clause when working tree clean in vscode？

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Im adding git.sync shortcut to my vscode
[image]

If I didnt commit , it shows
[image]

it means I need to add a proper when clause to my shortcut bindings:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "git.sync"
    "when":""
  },
```

so I need to add a when clause, whats it?

What I want to achieve finally is I can use cmd + enter to commit and sync(push to remote), because the sourcecontrol panel commit shortcut is cmd+ enter, I want to commit then sync use the same keyboard shortcut(instead of typing in terminal or click by mouse)

[image]

Comment: you can dump the current context to the Dev Tools console, look there is there is a context var that suits your needs

Comment: @rioV8

VM180:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

what's the name of var

Comment: find the commandId and `when` clause of the commit keybinding `Cmd+Enter`, then create a keybinding for `Cmd+Enter` with command `runCommands` that has the same `when` and combines the commit commandId and the sync comandId

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing (VS Code 1.85), there is no such context key you can use to do this. To substantiate:

- You can see docs for available context keys in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts. I don't see anything that sounds useful there when searching "scm" or "git".
- Neither do I see anything undocumented by searching `"when":.*scm` with regex mode on in the defaultKeybindings.json pseudo-file.
- Neither do I see anything undocumented by searching github.dev/microsoft/vscode. Searching `(createKey|createScoped|createOverlayy|setContext|removeContext|getContext|createChildContext).*?(git|scm)` with regex mode on,

  - There's a `git.state` context key, but the only values listed for its type definition `APIState` in [extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts) are `'initialized'` and `'uninitialized'`.
  - There's also the `gitRebaseInProgress` and `gitMergeInProgress` context keys, but I don't think those are sufficient to get what you want.
  - There's also `scmActiveResourceHasChanges` and `scmActiveResourceRepository`, but those are only for the active resource (singular) and not the whole repository.
- And looking at the existing issue tickets, I don't see one already asking for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Acontext-keys.

So I'd suggest that you [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for it.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.